# form variable names with square brackets in

Tags: html, arrays, forms, variables, square-bracket

when upload files, I make something like 'preview'. It stores form variables as

```
for(i=0;i<count($UpFile);i++){ //loop
<input name="Files[',htmlspecialchars($UpFile_name[$i]),'][FileName]" type="text" value="',htmlspecialchars($UpFile_name[$i]),'">
<input name="Files[',htmlspecialchars($UpFile_name[$i]),'][FileSize]" type="text" value="',htmlspecialchars($UpFile_size[$i]),'">
```

and then after submittting, when `$Files` is array I work with saved files, using their names as variables names.

The issue is, when I upload file with the name `file[123].jpg`, then php look at it not as `$Files['file[123].jpg']`, but as `$Files[$file[123].jpg']`. In other words, form record not found.

How to store names for form inputs to preserve square brackets, if there're ones in filenames?

Answer (score 0):

```
$SpecReplace=Array('['=>'&#91;',']'=>'&#93;');
<input name="Files[',htmlspecialchars(strtr($UpFile_name[$i],$SpecReplace)),'][FileName]" type="text"
```

replacing brackets to html special chars helped =)